# Parts environment in exam class does not display properly

Tags: exam

In the NQMWE (not quite minimal working example) below, one question has two `parts`:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\pointsinrightmargin

\begin{document}

\header{English 245}{Quiz on \emph{Childhood's End}, pp. 1--23}{2019/02/26}

\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Name: \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\dotfill}

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent Score: \makebox[1in]{\dotfill} of a possible \numpoints ~points

\begin{questions}
\question The Overlords make two demonstrations of their powers. What are they?
    \begin{parts}
        \part [1]
            \begin{solution}[1in]
            They destroy an incoming missile
            \end{solution}
        \part [1]
            \begin{solution}[1in]
            They block out the sun over Cape Town.
            \end{solution}
    \end{parts}

\question [1] The Overlords communicate through which medium?
\begin{choices}
\choice Written messages
\correctchoice Speech
\choice Video
\choice Musical tones
\end{choices}
\question [1] The Overlords' human liaison works for which organization?
\begin{choices}
\correctchoice The United Nations
\choice The World Health Organization
\choice The US government
\choice The Soviet government
\end{choices}
\question [1] The human opposition to the Overlords focuses on which of the following?
\begin{choices}
\choice \label{choice:cruelty} The cruelty of their rule
\choice \label{choice:concealment}The fact that they choose not to reveal themselves to their subjects
\choice \label{choice:sovereignty}The loss of human sovereignty
\correctchoice \ref{choice:concealment} and ~\ref{choice:sovereignty}, but not ~\ref{choice:cruelty}
\choice \ref{choice:cruelty} and ~\ref{choice:sovereignty}, but not ~\ref{choice:concealment}
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the `parts` in the first question don't appear, but everything else works correctly (see image below). (This is why I included the entire file: all the choices, labels, etc. work fine, except in the `parts` environment.)
[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you use `\begin{solution}` inside `\part` s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide additional text for `\parts [1]` to print so the part labels do not print. You can add text prompts for each part (e.g., "Demonstration 1") or you can make a zero thickness line to function as the text prompt to show only the part label. I added an example of each to your code.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\pointsinrightmargin

\begin{document}

\header{English 245}{Quiz on \emph{Childhood's End}, pp. 1--23}{2019/02/26}

\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Name: \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\dotfill}

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent Score: \makebox[1in]{\dotfill} of a possible \numpoints ~points

\begin{questions}
\question The Overlords make two demonstrations of their powers. What are they?
    \begin{parts}
        \part [1] Demonstration 1: % Use a text prompt
            \begin{solution}[1in]
            They destroy an incoming missile
            \end{solution}
        \part [1] \rule{1em}{0pt}  % Use an 0 thickness line
            \begin{solution}[1in]
            They block out the sun over Cape Town.
            \end{solution}
    \end{parts}

\question [1] The Overlords communicate through which medium?
\begin{choices}
\choice Written messages
\correctchoice Speech
\choice Video
\choice Musical tones
\end{choices}
\question [1] The Overlords' human liaison works for which organization?
\begin{choices}
\correctchoice The United Nations
\choice The World Health Organization
\choice The US government
\choice The Soviet government
\end{choices}
\question [1] The human opposition to the Overlords focuses on which of the following?
\begin{choices}
\choice \label{choice:cruelty} The cruelty of their rule
\choice \label{choice:concealment}The fact that they choose not to reveal themselves to their subjects
\choice \label{choice:sovereignty}The loss of human sovereignty
\correctchoice \ref{choice:concealment} and ~\ref{choice:sovereignty}, but not ~\ref{choice:cruelty}
\choice \ref{choice:cruelty} and ~\ref{choice:sovereignty}, but not ~\ref{choice:concealment}
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `solution` environment within `\part`s:

```
\begin{document}

\header{English 245}{Quiz on \emph{Childhood's End}, pp. 1--23}{2019/02/26}

\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Name: \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\dotfill}

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent Score: \makebox[1in]{\dotfill} of a possible \numpoints ~points

\begin{questions}
\question The Overlords make two demonstrations of their powers. What are they?
    \begin{parts}
        \part [1]
            %\begin{solution}[1in]
            They destroy an incoming missile
            %\end{solution}
        \part [1]
            %\begin{solution}[1in]
            They block out the sun over Cape Town.
            %\end{solution}
    \end{parts}

\question [1] The Overlords communicate through which medium?
\begin{choices}
\choice Written messages
\correctchoice Speech
\choice Video
\choice Musical tones
\end{choices}
\question [1] The Overlords' human liaison works for which organization?
\begin{choices}
\correctchoice The United Nations
\choice The World Health Organization
\choice The US government
\choice The Soviet government
\end{choices}
\question [1] The human opposition to the Overlords focuses on which of the following?
\begin{choices}
\choice \label{choice:cruelty} The cruelty of their rule
\choice \label{choice:concealment}The fact that they choose not to reveal themselves to their subjects
\choice \label{choice:sovereignty}The loss of human sovereignty
\correctchoice \ref{choice:concealment} and ~\ref{choice:sovereignty}, but not ~\ref{choice:cruelty}
\choice \ref{choice:cruelty} and ~\ref{choice:sovereignty}, but not ~\ref{choice:concealment}
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `solution` environment is not the problem. Each part can have its own solution. Removing the `solution` environment shows the solution on the quiz, which I am sure is not what the OP wants.